# How to bind a list view in a listbox data template WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a class called letter with a collection of objects but when I bind the item source to the list box the components objects within the data template for the listview the properties are null

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="lstDTGame">
        <WrapPanel  Height="30">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            <ListView></ListView>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Component}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True"
                              ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                        Width="100"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Point}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Class**

```
public class Letter
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to initialize that ObservableCollection in constructor or

   public ObservableCollection Components { get; set; }=
   new ObservableCollection< Component>();

2.You have bind your listView with Component, but you need to bind to ObservableCollection Components.

3.Check that your DataContext is properly set.

Comment: Also add the INotifyPropertyChanged in the Letter class and add the OnPropertyChanged event in the Component collection.

Comment: I think (2) is the main issue. Typical *check your debugging output window for Binding Error entries*.